# Searching for text in a .txt

Tags: c#, search, text

What would be the best way to search a text file that looks like this..?

> efee|| Nbr| Address| Name      |Phone|City|State|Zip 
>  abc
>   ||455|gsgd   |first last|gsg  |fef |jk   |0393
>  gjgj||jfj|ddg
>   |first last|fht  |ree |hn   |th ...more lines...

I started by reading in the file and all its contexts with a streamreader
I was thinking to count the "|" and grab the text between the 5th and 6th using substring but i'm not sure how to do the count of the "|". Or if someone has a better idea I'm open to it.
Tried something like this:

```
StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"...");
        string line;
        int num=0;
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
            {
                if (line.Contains("|"))
                {
                    num++;
                }
            }
            int start = line.IndexOf("|");

            int end = line.IndexOf("|");
            string result = line.Substring(start, end - start - 1);
        }
```

The text I want I beleive is always between the 5th and 6th "|"

Comment: Use the .NET TextFieldParser class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
var res = File
    .ReadLines(@"FileName.txt")
    .Select(line => line.Split(new[]{'|'}, StringSplitOptions.None)[5])
    .ToList();
```

This produces a `List<strings>` from the file, where each string is the part of the corresponding line of the file taken from between the fifth and the sixth `'|'` separator.

Comment: get the erro cannot convert stringsplitoptions to char

Comment: @ERead This should be fixed now.

Comment: Yup that works great. now I just gotta manipulate what I extracted out and split it into two diff strings, first name and last name

Comment: Oh i should learn that LINQ is my friend I always forget LINQ

Answer (score 1):

For a delimited file you should use a parser - there is one in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO` namespace - the [`TextFieldParser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx) class, though you could also look at third-party libraries like the popular [FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/).

A simpler approach would be to use `string.Split` on the `|` character and getting the value in the corresponding index of the returned `string[]`, however, if any of the fields are escaped and can validly contain `|` internally, this will fail.

Answer (score 0):

You could split each line into an array:

```
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    var values = line.Split('|');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
string txt = File.ReadAllText("file.txt");
string res = Regex.Match(txt, "\\|*?{5}(.+?)\\|", RegexOptions.Singleline).Result("$1");
```